# Ending of "Under Suspicion"

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, under-suspicion

I just watched [Under Suspicion (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105691/) and I'm not sure I've understood the outcome of the movie.
Is it that Tony and Stassio's first wife screwed up everyone, framed Angelina, and got away, or I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](http://coffeebeancinema.blogspot.com/2011/07/under-suspicion-1991.html) explains:

> But Tony turns out alright, with Frank coming in at the nick of time
>   to save his life (literally) finding the dude's thumb in Angeline's
>   things. Angeline is caught and convicted - *whew* that was close - she
>   almost got away with it!
>
> If only things ended where they did, but no, they had to keep beating
>   a horse that had died many scenes ago. **Tony Aaron is revealed to be
>   his wife's and Stasio's killer and planting the thumb in Angeline's
>   house. Apparently, Tony was in cahoots with Stasio's wife to get some
>   of the money from Stasio's paintings.** Whoa - wait a tick - say what?

Comment: Nice. Pretty close to what I thought, but now that's even clearer and nicer with him being the crook. Good movie it was.